# Errors opening terminal, git, and xdebug with vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have not found a solution to similar questions here ... hoping someone can decipher these error logs for me?  Maybe my installation is corrupt?

Things that were working yesterday (and years before) but not today:

1. Does not open terminal from VS Code
2. Does not recognize my git folders
3. xdebug for PHP does not work

I verified that I have Node, NPM, and Git installed.

Here is the output:

```
Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/spdlog/build/Release/spdlog.node)
    at process.func [as dlopen] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:1812)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1250:18)
    at Object.func [as .node] (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:2039)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1039:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:932:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12738)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1079:19)
    at v (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:12287)
    at bindings (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/bindings/bindings.js:112:48)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar/spdlog/index.js:3:35)
    at Module.u._compile (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:12841)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1220:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1039:32)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:932:14)
    at Function.f._load (electron/js2c/asar_bundle.js:5:12738)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1079:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at t (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:101)
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:13249)
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10262)
    at c (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:10314)
    at Object.errorback (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:10435)
    at r.triggerErrorback (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10626)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10332
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:13266)
    at r.load (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:3:10262)
    at c (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:10314)
    at r._loadModule (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:10444)
    at r._resolve (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:5:452)
    at r.defineModule (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:6145)
    at r._relativeRequire (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:6831)
    at n (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/loader.js:4:9420)
    at m (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:28:41895)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at y (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:28:41875)
    at S._createSpdLogLogger (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:28:42850)
    at new S (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:28:42655)
    at /usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:1669
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Y.startup (/usr/share/code/resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-main/main.js:57:1448) {
  phase: 'loading',
  moduleId: 'spdlog',
  neededBy: [ '===anonymous3===' ]
}
[main 2021-02-19T21:47:36.128Z] update#setState idle
[main 2021-02-19T21:47:36.164Z] [storage state.vscdb] open(): Unable to open DB due to Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/vscode-sqlite3/build/Release/sqlite.node)
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
(node:10240) electron: The default of contextIsolation is deprecated and will be changing from false to true in a future release of Electron.  See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23506 for more information
[main 2021-02-19T21:47:36.305Z] [storage state.vscdb] open(): Unable to use backup due to Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, unlink '/home/mdegalli/.config/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb'
[main 2021-02-19T21:47:36.305Z] [storage] init(): Unable to init global storage due to Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/vscode-sqlite3/build/Release/sqlite.node)
[main 2021-02-19T21:47:36.505Z] [uncaught exception in main]: Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/vscode-sqlite3/build/Release/sqlite.node)
[main 2021-02-19T21:47:36.505Z] Error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /usr/share/code/resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/vscode-sqlite3/build/Release/sqlite.node)
```

Answer (score 0):

I rolled back my VS Code version to 1.52.1 and that solved the problem.  I was going to accept the answer from another user here, but their post disappeared.  Thanks to them for helping me solve this problem!